# Show all on option click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I got this filter where everything works perflectly. When I press specific category it will list only rows with that categories. But I realized that I don't know how to show them all after click on first option. My goal is. On "Categories" click show all rows and on specific category click show only specific category.

```js
highlightRows = () => {
    let oddRows = document.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr.show')
    oddRows.forEach((row, index)=> {
        if (index % 2 == 0) {
            row.style.background = '#f1f1f1'
        } else {
            row.style.background = '#fff'
        }
    })
}


const filterOptions = () => {
    const option = document.querySelector("#filter").value;
    const selection = option.replace('&', '')
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#body1 > tr");
  console.log(rows.length);
    
    rows.forEach(row => {
        let td = row.querySelector("td:last-child");
        let filter = td.innerText.replace('&', '');
        if (filter === selection) {
            row.className = 'show'
        } else {
            row.className = 'hidden'
    }

    });
    highlightRows()
};
document.getElementById("filter").addEventListener("change", filterOptions);
```

```css
.table-filters {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
.table-filters a {
  color: #222;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-right: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
.table-filters a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.table-filters select {
  background: #fff;

  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 12em;
  height: 2.5em;
}

table.stats {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
tbody tr.show {
  display: table-row;
}
tbody tr.hidden {
 display: none;
}
table.vypis {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table.vypis > caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table.vypis > tr.vypis-riadok {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}

table.vypis th,
table.vypis td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}

table.vypis th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  table.vypis {
    border: 0;
  }

  table.vypis > caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  
  table.vypis > thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  
  table.vypis tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  
  table.vypis td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  table.vypis td::before {

    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  table.vypis td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-filters">
        <select id="filter">
          <option selected value="none">Categories</option>
          <option>Hobby</option>
          <option>Others</option>

          
        </select>
      </div>
      <table class="vypis">
        <caption>Pohyby na účte</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Refer</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Category</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="body1">
          <tr class="vypis-riadok">
            <td scope="row" data-label="refer">[[X04_riadok_1_popis_transakcie]] <br> [[X10_riadok_2_popis_transakcie]]</td>
            <td data-label="date">[[X02_riadok_1_datum]]</td>
            <td data-label="price">[[X08_riadok_1_suma]] €</td>
            <td data-label="category">Others</td>
          </tr> 
                    <tr class="vypis-riadok">
            <td scope="row" data-label="refer">[[X04_riadok_1_popis_transakcie]] <br> [[X10_riadok_2_popis_transakcie]]</td>
            <td data-label="date">[[X02_riadok_1_datum]]</td>
            <td data-label="price">[[X08_riadok_1_suma]] €</td>
            <td data-label="category">Hobby</td>
          </tr> 
                    <tr class="vypis-riadok">
            <td scope="row" data-label="refer">[[X04_riadok_1_popis_transakcie]] <br> [[X10_riadok_2_popis_transakcie]]</td>
            <td data-label="date">[[X02_riadok_1_datum]]</td>
            <td data-label="price">[[X08_riadok_1_suma]] €</td>
            <td data-label="category">Others</td>
          </tr>
```

Comment: do you want to show everything when you select the first "Categories" parameter?

Comment: Yes @sergey kuznetsov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are adding `hidden` class so need to remove this when `categories` option is clicked so one way is to loop through `tr` and check if the `tr` contains that class and then just change it to `show` .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
highlightRows = () => {
  let oddRows = document.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr.show')
  oddRows.forEach((row, index) => {
    if (index % 2 == 0) {
      row.style.background = '#f1f1f1'
    } else {
      row.style.background = '#fff'
    }
  })
}


const filterOptions = () => {
  const option = document.querySelector("#filter").value;
  const selection = option.replace('&', '')
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#body1 > tr");
  //check if value is not none
  if (option != "none") {
    rows.forEach(row => {
      let td = row.querySelector("td:last-child");
      let filter = td.innerText.replace('&', '');
      if (filter === selection) {
        row.className = 'show'
      } else {
        row.className = 'hidden'
      }

    });
    highlightRows()
  } else {
 //loop though rows
    rows.forEach(row => {
    //check if row has class hidden
      if (row.classList.contains("hidden")) {
        row.className = 'show'//add showclass
      }      
    })
    highlightRows()
  }

};
document.getElementById("filter").addEventListener("change", filterOptions);
```

```css
.table-filters {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.table-filters a {
  color: #222;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-right: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.table-filters a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.table-filters select {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 12em;
  height: 2.5em;
}

table.stats {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

tbody tr.show {
  display: table-row;
}

tbody tr.hidden {
  display: none;
}

table.vypis {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table.vypis>caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table.vypis>tr.vypis-riadok {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}

table.vypis th,
table.vypis td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}

table.vypis th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-filters">
  <select id="filter">
    <option selected value="none">Categories</option>
    <option>Hobby</option>
    <option>Others</option>


  </select>
</div>
<table class="vypis">
  <caption>Pohyby na účte</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Refer</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Price</th>
      <th scope="col">Category</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="body1">
    <tr class="vypis-riadok">
      <td scope="row" data-label="refer">[[X04_riadok_1_popis_transakcie]] <br> [[X10_riadok_2_popis_transakcie]]</td>
      <td data-label="date">[[X02_riadok_1_datum]]</td>
      <td data-label="price">[[X08_riadok_1_suma]] €</td>
      <td data-label="category">Others</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="vypis-riadok">
      <td scope="row" data-label="refer">[[X04_riadok_1_popis_transakcie]] <br> [[X10_riadok_2_popis_transakcie]]</td>
      <td data-label="date">[[X02_riadok_1_datum]]</td>
      <td data-label="price">[[X08_riadok_1_suma]] €</td>
      <td data-label="category">Hobby</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="vypis-riadok">
      <td scope="row" data-label="refer">[[X04_riadok_1_popis_transakcie]] <br> [[X10_riadok_2_popis_transakcie]]</td>
      <td data-label="date">[[X02_riadok_1_datum]]</td>
      <td data-label="price">[[X08_riadok_1_suma]] €</td>
      <td data-label="category">Others</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this soultion work, but only on desktop version when I resize, so filter stop working on mobile version. @Swati

Comment: Your previous code was working  with mobile ? If yes this should also work .

Comment: yes it was. You can try it when you resize monitor. There was only problem with that "Category" option. But now I desktop version works well, but mobile version is not working anymore

Comment: I have remove that css for `media` did you add that again while testing on your end ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/08XI/pen/mdrPOPy
Here you can see my old code. Try to resize window. It worked well because there was 
tbody tr.hidden {
 display: none !important;
}

Comment: Oh wait...I added there your code and it works...but iny my project it doesn't work...hmmm there must be problem somewhere else...

Comment: are you seeing any error in console ? I have already tested it on my end it was working that's the reason i told you it should work :) Let me know if still didn't solved.